# Using pandas "where" change values of an entry conditioning on all values in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Problem modeling:

Let say we have data frame

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'b' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'c' : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'd' : [5, 1, 2 ,1, 1 ,22, 30, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
```

We want to change 0 to 100 only if all values in the particular column are zero. 
In our case this is column 'c'.

In the end we would have

```
'a' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'b' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'c' : [ 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
'd' : [5, 1, 2 ,1, 1 ,22, 30, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
```

I was thinking about `DF.where(...)` but struggle to set right condition.
Probably there is another way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.all()` and `.loc`, eg:

```
DF.loc[:, DF.eq(0).all()] = 100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'b' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'c' : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'd' : [5, 1, 2 ,1, 1 ,22, 30, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
for column in df.columns:
    if (df[column]==0).all():
        df[column] = 100
```

Comment: mrzo's solution is elegant but the problem with it that you have to apply it on ALL columns including C itself. Please check my solution below that allows you o pick exactly which columns this should apply to,

Answer (score 0):

mrzo's solution is elegant but the problem with it that you have to apply it on ALL columns including C itself. The solution below should allow you to pick exactly which columns this should apply to:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'b' : [ 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'c' : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'd' : [5, 1, 2 ,1, 1 ,22, 30, 1, 0, 0, 0]})


df['SUM'] = df['a'] + df['b'] + df['d']
df['c'] = df['SUM'].apply(lambda x: 100 if x>0 else x)
df
```